# MongoDB sharded replicated cluster for production deployment

Tags: mongodb

I want to deploy a Mongodb replicated sharded cluster for production -

- 2 Replica Set: R11, R21, R31, R21, R22, R23 (1 primary, 2 secondary
  in each set)
- 3 Config Servers - C1, C2, C3
- 1 Mongos - M1

My Qs are -

1. Is Ci is on a different machine than Rij? What is recommended? I know this depends on the usage but what is recommended? I read in the docs that it is recommended to use 3 different machines for Ci's. Does it mean these 3 machines must be different from the ones used for Rij's?
2. Is M1 on a different machine than Ci and Rij Or I can just use, say, R11 for M1.

My use case - 
For the first six months, my data is manageable. It can become huge over a period of time, say in a year.

Comment: You can put configs on the same servers as Replicas. Config does not handle a lot of things and therefore can be put on the same machines. Or you can put the on some really old machines.

Comment: However putting configs on the same server as the replica kinda defeats the point of having 3 redundant config servers. MongoDB is all about redundancy, you take that away and you might as well be using a single machine setup

Comment: One method is running a mongos per application server actually, and getting that application to talk to localhost. That has worked quite well for me in the past

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to answer this with some notes.

> Is Ci is on a different machine than Rij?

As @SalvadorDali said you can place your config servers onto your shard/mongos/whatever servers. They just house configuration information for your mongos routers to propogate their own configuration from so they know how your cluster is built up and how it functions.

> What is recommended?

MongoDB thrives upon redundancy. Even though you can put them on the same server that would be lowering your redundancy and in turn your ability to overcome ciritical failure.

It is strongly recommended to get three extremely low powered machines for these, hell you can even run a config server on a mobile phone (of course you wouldn't for obvious reasons, one being that it doesn't contain a compatible processor for MongoDB).

> Does it mean these 3 machines must be different from the ones used for Rij's?

They *should* be. Only in a test environment would you want to reduce the redundancy of your cluster.

> Is M1 on a different machine than Ci and Rij Or I can just use, say, R11 for M1.

M1 is actually on a different machine typically. Numerous times the best setup has been found to use a mongos per application server and have the application call `localhost` in its programming. This way your mongos instances are not tied to a set of external instances but instead to the availability of your application. Lets face it if your application is unavailable then there isn't much point in your mongos instances being available...

Answer (score 1):

he smallest configuration for you is to use 3 servers.

> *>>> 1.Is Ci is on a different machine than Rij?*

Ci can be with Rij on the same machines. Look on the image below.

> *>>> What is recommended?*

There is no strict recommendation about configuration, but if you want that you system was high available, you just need to deploy Ci servers on the different machines and distribute Rij between them. One rule is to use no less then RF (replica factor) servers for your configuration. For your case RF=3 that means at least 3 machines.

> *>>> I read in the docs that it is recommended to use 3 different machines for Ci's. Does it mean these 3 machines must be different
>   from the ones used for Rij's?*

No, you can use these 3 machines to share them between Rij and Ci.

> *>>> Is M1 on a different machine than Ci and Rij Or I can just use, say, R11 for M1.*

M1 can be deployed on the same machines where both Ci and Rij.

The smallest configuration:

[image: The smallest configuration]
The middle configuration: 
[image]
The most disaster recovering configuration: To use separate server for each mongod and mongos instances.

Comment: I would strongly recommend shooting yourself in the foot before placing two replicas on the same server, plus you will find that resource contention will be a major issue here

Comment: The most redundant solution would not be a sever per mongos, mongos is just a router, it can sit on the application end if it wants. In fact that would be better due to latency etc

Comment: About mongos you are right. I agrre :) I've edited article :) Thank you :)

Comment: About two replica sets, as I told, this is the smallest configuration and not fault-tolerant enought :)

Comment: Its not just about fault tolerant, it is about resource contention as well, mongod uses a lot of resources, putting multiple replica members on the same sever will most likely result in performance downgrading

Comment: It's better to use separte sever for each mongod, but sometimes it's too expensive. For inexpensive solution, it's OK. Besides, as you can see, primaries replicas are on the different servers (R11 is on the Server1, R21 is on the Server3).

Comment: If it is too expensive you would better off performance and redundancy wise to use single server setup, the seocndaries can have just as many ops as the primaries and if the seocndaries resources are loaded they can suffer replication lag, plus in a failover situation that new primary will now be loaded by the secondary

Comment: We can talk about it infinitely, but the question is about recommended configurations. MongoDB suggests to use not less than RF number servers to deploy servers. It means it's possible to use 3, but it's better to use 6 or even 9. If I deployed my configuration I would use 6 for this case :).